# How to navigate using SafeArgs

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-safe-args

I just started to use the Jetpack Navigation components and SafeArgs for navigation in Android. However, I do not understand how I can navigate from one destination to another one (I read the google documentation but this was confusing for me). So I have a Menu_Fragment class that has a link in the NavGraph to a Softdrink class. A Menu_FragmentDirections class was automatically created. However, I do not know how to use it within the Menu_Fragment class to implement an OnClick listener event. Here I have the onClick method in the Menu_Fragment class (see https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButton_Softdrinks_en) {
        float amount = ...;
        action =
                Menu_FragmentDirections
                        .actionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks(amount);
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);

    }

}
```

Here you can see the Menu_FragmentDirections class:

```
package com.example.td.barapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.navigation.ActionOnlyNavDirections;
import androidx.navigation.NavDirections;

public class Menu_FragmentDirections {
  private Menu_FragmentDirections() {
  }

  @NonNull
  public static NavDirections actionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks() {
    return new ActionOnlyNavDirections(R.id.action_menu_Fragment_to_softdrinks);
  }
}
```

And here you can see the NavGraph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/menu_Fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_Fragment"
        android:name="com.example.td.barapp.Menu_Fragment"
        android:label="fragment_menu_"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_menu_Fragment_to_softdrinks"
            app:destination="@id/softdrinks" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/softdrinks"
        android:name="com.example.td.barapp.Softdrinks"
        android:label="fragment_softdrinks"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_softdrinks" />
</navigation>
```

Can anybody tell me, what I have to do in the onCreateMethod() posted above.I get the error messages:
"Cannot resolve symbol 'action'" and "Cannot resolve symbol 'Navigation'" (and of course the error for using the unexpected token '...')

I'd appreciate every comment and would be quite thankful for your help.

Update here is the complete Menu_Fragment class with the onCreateMethod:

```
package com.example.td.barapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.td.barapp.databinding.FragmentMenuBinding;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link Menu_Fragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Menu_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;



    private Menu_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Menu_Fragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Menu_Fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Menu_Fragment fragment = new Menu_Fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }


    }

    private FragmentMenuBinding binding;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding.imageButtonCocktailsEn.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonCocktailsAlcfreeEn.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonLongdrinksEn.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonWhiskyEn.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonLiquorEn.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonBeerEn.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonSoftdrinksEn.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.imageButtonHotDrinksEn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.imageButton_Softdrinks_en) {
            float amount = 0f;
            Menu_FragmentDirections.ActionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks  action = Menu_FragmentDirections
                    .actionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks(amount);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can i see the full errorLog, Vanessa?

Comment: Thanks Felix for your comment. Basically when I compile I only get one error "error: illegal start of expression
            float amount = ...;". But in the class itself I have more errors as posted above ""Cannot resolve symbol 'action'" and "Cannot resolve symbol 'Navigation'""

Comment: Where do I have to initialize the Navigation object? I think I have not done this yet and also the action Object. It can't find the object navigation.

Comment: You didn't post the "onCreateMethod()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the object type before the action.

It would like like this:

```
Menu_FragmentDirections.ActionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks action = Menu_FragmentDirections
                    .actionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks(amount);
```

And the error:

> error: illegal start of expression float amount = ...;

It's because you want a float and you are passing "...". It must be a floating number.

Ie:`float amount = 0.6f` or `float amount = 0f`.

EDIT:

To add an argument to a fragment, please do the following steps:

Select the destination fragment and click on the plus as highlighted.
[image]

After that, choose the type of variable you want and give it a name
[image]

Rebuild your project and check it if it's now working.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo for your answer. I used your code but I get an error message "Cannot resolve symbol 'ActionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks'". Further, I do not know which value I should choose for the float (I used 0f for it without understanding it).

Comment: I just added the java code of the complete class. Maybe this will help you getting a better understanding of what's going wrong. I'd really appreciate every comment from you.

Comment: Just a question before I change my answer: after adding the action on your NavGraph, did you rebuild your project? You need to do that in order to Android Studio recognize the actions

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo for your comment and help. When I rebuilid I get an error message "error: cannot find symbol
            Menu_FragmentDirections.ActionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks  action = Menu_FragmentDirections
                                   ^
  symbol:   class ActionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks
  location: class Menu_FragmentDirections"

Comment: Try to comment that line of code, rebuild, and when is finishes the rebuild start typing `Menu_FragmentDirections.` and see if your action appears

Comment: I did that and when I type Menu_FragmentDirections.actionMenuFragmentToSoftdrinks()

Comment: Meanwhile I found another google develper description for the same thing with different code: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started. But this does also not work because "NavDirections" and "Navigation" cannot be found. I think this the problem. I do not define them. Where and how can I define those variables?

Comment: NavDirections and Navigation are premade classes. They are from the JetPack Navigation library. I saw in your Menu_Fragment class that you didn't import those classes

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo for your answer and help. Why are they not automatically imported? And shall I use the approach with the float or without the float?

Comment: Sometimes Android Studio does that. Depends on your needs. If you need to send a variable to the next fragment, you should stick with the float approach

Comment: But normally I never use floats. Might be possible that I send strings or images from one Fragment to the other but not floats. By the way, the float approach still does not work because of the action variable that can't be resolved.

Comment: Check my anwer again. I add an edit that will solve your problem I think

Comment: Thanks Rodgrigo for your answer and help. Why do I need these arguments and what are they used for? Still I do not understand which number I should use for them. If I have an int should it be a 2, 45, 26778 etc.?

Comment: Those arguments are used to pass variables from one fragment to another. Imagine that you have 5 apples and you need to tell the next fragment that you have 5 apples. You would use that arguments to pass an integer with that number 5

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks Rodgrigo for your tremendous help.

Comment: You're very welcome! If my answer was the right one, It would mean a lot to me if you mark it as the correct one please

Comment: Hi Rodgrigo. Yes, I did that. Thanks for your help and effort.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anybody tell me, what I have to do in the onCreateMethod() posted above.I get the error messages: "Cannot resolve symbol 'action'" and "Cannot resolve symbol 'Navigation'" (and of course the error for using the unexpected token '...')

Here's what I think, there is a problem in your **navGraph.xml**, you intend to pass a SafeArg from `MenuFragment` to `SoftDrinksFragment` but you are not writing code to make that work that is why your `action` cannot be resolved.

Edit your navGraph.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/menu_Fragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_Fragment"
        android:name="com.example.td.barapp.Menu_Fragment"
        android:label="fragment_menu_"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_menu" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_menu_Fragment_to_softdrinks"
            app:destination="@id/softdrinks" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/softdrinks"
        android:name="com.example.td.barapp.Softdrinks"
        android:label="fragment_softdrinks"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_softdrinks">
        <argument
            android:name="amount"
            app:argType="integer" />
    </fragment>
    
</navigation>
```

Also to resolve the problem with `Navigation`
Make sure to add this dependency to your gradle file

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$2.3.0"
```

the add this line to the top of your gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220553/discussion-on-answer-by-felix-favour-chinemerem-how-to-navigate-using-safeargs).